# If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x}{y}$, is $\frac{x-a}{y-b}=\frac{x}{y}$?

Tags: fractions, ratio

Does this hold?  $b,y \neq 0$, $b \neq y$.

Comment: it holds but you need to prove it (it's not obvious),

Comment: For a concrete example: $\frac36=\frac12$, and $\frac{3-1}{6-2}=\frac24=\frac12$.

Comment: Let $\,v = (x,y),\ c = (b,-a)=0,\ d = (a,b).\ $ Then $\ v\cdot c = 0 = d\cdot c\,\Rightarrow (v-d)\cdot c = v\cdot c - d\cdot c = 0-0 = 0.\ $ Note $\,v-d = (x-a,y-b).\ $ If you know about vector spaces (or modules) you can use them to help understand the innate lineartiy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So by $\frac ab = \frac xy$ we have $x = ka$, $y = kb$ for some $k \ne 0,1$. This gives 
$$ \frac{x-a}{y-b}  = \frac{ka - a}{kb- b} = \frac{a(k-1)}{b(k-1)} = \frac ab = \frac xy. $$

Comment: perfect thanks.

Comment: Note that $k$ here does not need to be an integer.

Comment: Of course${}{}{}$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{x}{y}$ then $ay=xb$ so $xy-ay=xy-xb$, $y(x-a)=x(y-b) \to \dfrac{x-a}{y-b}=\dfrac{x}{y}$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}&=\frac{x}{y}\\
\frac{x}{a}&=\frac{y}{b}\\
\frac{x}{a}-1&=\frac{y}{b}-1\\
\frac{x-a}{a}&=\frac{y-b}{b}\\
\frac{x-a}{y-b}&=\frac{a}{b}\\
\frac{x-a}{y-b}&=\frac{x}{y}
\end{align}

Comment: It wasn't rendering (at least, not on an iPhone) so I edited it. Feel free to revert it if you want.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Strange: possibly a different version of MathJax?